# Не запускается html страница в Docker

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, docker

На убунту 18.04 создала в ручную папку test1 по адресу `/home/pk/test1/`.
В нее положила 2 файла `Dockerfile` и `index.html`. Мне надо вывести содержимое файла `index.html` в браузере используя Docker.

Содержимое `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx:latest
WORKDIR /home/pk/test1/
COPY index.html /home/pk/test1/index.html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Содержимое файла `index.html`:

```
<html>
<h1>hello world</h1>
</html>
```

Из папки `/home/pk/test1/` я открываю терминал, потом в терминале прописываю команду создания образа сайта: `docker build -t site4:v3` . Все проходит нормально. Ниже приведено, что терминал выдал на ввод этой команды:

```
pk@pk:~/test1$ docker build -t site4:v3 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB

Step 1/5 : FROM nginx:latest
 ---> 719cd2e3ed04
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /home/pk/test1/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4ff97fecabba
Step 3/5 : COPY index.html /home/pk/test1/index.html
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6d60a28e7bba
Step 4/5 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 11b68a780d2e
Step 5/5 : CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 147a1927455d
Successfully built 147a1927455d
Successfully tagged site4:v3
```

Дальше я в терминале пробрасываю порт 1237 к порту 80:

```
docker run -d -p 1237:80 site4:v3
```

В ответ терминал выдал сообщение, что все в порядке (id написал):

```
pk@pk:~/test1$ docker run -d -p 1237:80 site4:v3
cea7af3aa7d330e0ef211016bfe07f1f19c06d725f595516b4939bf5a336abc4
```

Далее в браузере я набираю команду: http://localhost:1237/. И вместо фразы "Hello world" вижу такое: Welcome to nginx!

> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed
>   and working. Further configuration is required.
>
> For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
>   Commercial support is available at nginx.com.
>
> Thank you for using nginx.

Никто не подскажет как исправить дело?

Comment: Конфиг nginx'а то покажите)

Comment: извиняюсь за глупый вопрос. Я только начинаю работать в нем. Этот файл нужно сделать? Имеется ввиду конфиг

Answer (score 0):

Я этот образ не использовал, но, судя по [документации](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/), класть файлы надо в `/usr/share/nginx/html`, а не `/home/pk/test1/`.

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию, как замечено выше, nginx "смотрит" файлы сайта в папке /usr/share/nginx/html

Соответственно, файл index.html Вам нужно скопировать в данную папку в образе.

```
FROM nginx:latest
WORKDIR /home/pk/test1/
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```